# is it possible to filter different elements with checkboxes?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, filter

I found this code, and i want to improve it to work with different elements. Now it works only with one div class, but what if i want it to work with something like this:

```
<div class="list">

<li class="one category1">               //get some category from this li
<a href="link">
<img src="img"/>
<p class="name">name</p></a>
<p class="age">Age: days</p>
<span class="rating category2"></span>   //get some category from this span
<span class="status category3"></span></li>   //get some category from this span

...code repeats from <li class="one category1"> to </li> many times with different values and that the content i filter
```

code i found:

```
    <ul id="filter1">
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="filter1" value="dark">
            Dark</li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="filter1" value="medium">
            Medium</li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="filter1" value="light">
            Light</li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="filter2">
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="filter2" value="sm">
            Small</li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="filter2" value="med">
            Medium</li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="filter2" value="lge">
            Large</li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="filter3">
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="filter3" value="smooth">
            Smooth</li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="filter3" value="riven">
            Riven</li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="filter3" value="honed">
            Honed</li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="filter4">
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="filter4" value="a">
            Up to £25</li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="filter4" value="b">
            £25 to £45</li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="filter4" value="c">
            £45 to £65</li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="filter4" value="d">
            £65 to £85</li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="filter4" value="e">
            over £85</li>
    </ul>

    <p><a class="showall" href="#" />Clear Filters</a></p>

    <div class="list dark sm smooth b">dark small smooth b</div>
    <div class="list medium lge honed d">medium large honed d</div>
    <div class="list dark med smooth d">dark medium smooth d</div>
    <div class="list light sm smooth b">light small smooth b</div>
    <div class="list light lge riven b">light large riven b</div>
    <div class="list dark sm riven c">dark small riven c</div>
    <div class="list medium med riven a">medium medium riven a</div>
    <div class="list medium lge honed e">medium large honed e</div>

    <div class="NoResults"></div>

    <script>

        $("#filter1 :checkbox,#filter2 :checkbox,#filter3 :checkbox,#filter4 :checkbox").click(function () {

            $("div.list").hide();

            var Filter1Array = [];
            var Filter2Array = [];
            var Filter3Array = [];
            var Filter4Array = [];
            var filter1_Count = 0, filter2_Count = 0, filter3_Count = 0, filter4_Count = 0;

            $("#filter1 :checkbox:checked").each(function () {
                Filter1Array[filter1_Count] = $(this).val();
                filter1_Count++
            });

            $("#filter2 :checkbox:checked").each(function () {
                Filter2Array[filter2_Count] = $(this).val();
                filter2_Count++
            });

            $("#filter3 :checkbox:checked").each(function () {
                Filter3Array[filter3_Count] = $(this).val();
                filter3_Count++
            });

            $("#filter4 :checkbox:checked").each(function () {
                Filter4Array[filter4_Count] = $(this).val();
                filter4_Count++
            });

            var filter1string
            var filter2string
            var filter3string
            var filter4string

            var filter1checked = false
            var filter2checked = false
            var filter3checked = false
            var filter4checked = false

            if (filter1_Count == 0) { filter1_Count = 1; } else { filter1checked = true; }
            if (filter2_Count == 0) { filter2_Count = 1; } else { filter2checked = true; }
            if (filter3_Count == 0) { filter3_Count = 1; } else { filter3checked = true; }
            if (filter4_Count == 0) { filter4_Count = 1; } else { filter4checked = true; }

            for (f1 = 0; f1 < filter1_Count; f1++) {

                if (Filter1Array[f1] != null) { filter1string = '.' + Filter1Array[f1] } else { filter1string = '' }

                for (f2 = 0; f2 < filter2_Count; f2++) {

                    if (Filter2Array[f2] != null) { filter2string = '.' + Filter2Array[f2] } else { filter2string = '' }

                    for (f3 = 0; f3 < filter3_Count; f3++) {

                        if (Filter3Array[f3] != null) { filter3string = '.' + Filter3Array[f3] } else { filter3string = '' }

                        for (f4 = 0; f4 < filter4_Count; f4++) {

                            if (Filter4Array[f4] != null) { filter4string = '.' + Filter4Array[f4] } else { filter4string = '' }

                            var QueryString = filter1string + filter2string + filter3string + filter4string
                            $(QueryString).fadeIn('fast');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!filter1checked && !filter2checked && !filter3checked && !filter4checked) {
                $("div.list").fadeIn('fast');
            };

            if ($('div.list:visible').length === 0) {
                $(".NoResults").html("<p class='error'>No products match your filter selections. Please try a different combination.</p>");
            }
            else { $(".NoResults").html(""); }

        });

        $('a.showall').click(function () {
            $("div.list").fadeIn('fast');
            $("#filter1 :checkbox").removeAttr('checked');
            $("#filter2 :checkbox").removeAttr('checked');
            $("#filter3 :checkbox").removeAttr('checked');
            $("#filter4 :checkbox").removeAttr('checked');
            $(".NoResults").html("");
            return false;
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Every help will be very much appreciated

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what you're after here. What does "filter different elements" mean?

Comment: it means that code i have can filter only stuff which is in one div class and i want to for example filter one thing from div class, second from span class and third from paragraph class.

Comment: Sorry, but that's no clearer. Try explaining without using the word "filter". It's too vague of a term.

Comment: what are your filtering rules? Code you have is awful and can certainly be shortened up a lot, but need better guidelines on expected behavior

Comment: i think that answers for both of you are in first code sample. filtering rules are category1 , category2 and category3, and as you see isherwood everyone of those categories is in different element

Comment: you may think it is self explanatory but I can think of several ways to interpret based on `either/or` or `match all`. Also don't see relationship between checkboxes and category.. is not clear

Comment: By filter do you mean show/hide?

Comment: oh you ment this, by filtering rules sorry i am not very good in english. lets make myself clear. for example: category1 will be replaced with car lorry bus (result <li class="one car lorry bus">) . category2 will be replaced with fast slow , so it will narrow down selection from category1 (car lorry bus) and category3 will be rating lets say 1s 2s 3s 4s 5s, like star rating, which will narrow result even more.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the folowing is along the lines of what you are after, although details given so far are very vague

```
var filterArray=[];

$(function(){    
    var $items=$('#items .list'), $noRes=$('.NoResults')

   var $controls = $(':checkbox').change(function(){
        if(this.checked){
            filterArray.push(this.value)
        }else{
           var idx= $.inArray(this.value, filterArray);
            filterArray.splice( idx,1);     
        }      
        filterItems();          
    });


    $('a.showall').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $controls.prop('checked',false);
        filterArray=[];
        filterItems();
    });

    function filterItems(){
      var results=0;
      if( filterArray.length){          
              $items.hide(); 
              var $filterItems=$items.filter( '.'+filterArray.join('.')).show()
              results=$filterItems.length;
          }else{
              $items.show();
          }
          $noRes[results || !filterArray.length ? 'hide' : 'show' ]();
    }
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/xB6Xb/1

Without rules for how to handle user selecting more than one price or more than one item in each category it is hard to do more.

**Edit** fixed bug with `no results` display

Comment: its good, but when i want it to select filter from <p class="dark small smooth"> inside <div class="list> it still dont work. and since you spoke about rules about selecting more than one item per category, how that could be done?

Comment: goes back to you never defined the rules in the first place... It's time for you to make those specific rules. I really don' know what you want. What does `it still dont work` mean??

Comment: when I check `dark,small,smooth` I get the first item displayed

Comment: i ment it like this. i wantet this filter to work with diferent element classes. now it works only with classes stored in one div, so if i want it to filter classes from childrens of this div it will not work. another thing is if i want to select more checkboxes from same group of filters of will return no results.

Comment: here is fiddle of what i want, but script there works only with classes of one div, again dont work with its childrens classes. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ar3PY/2/)